# MongoDB returns object data as array of key-value pair in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation

I have written following query which returns me records where updated_at date is greater than synced_at date from all records using mongodb library in Golang.

```
    pipeline := []bson.M{}
    filter := []string{"$updated_at", "$synced_at"}
    pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"$expr": bson.M{"$gte": filter}}})
    opts := options.Aggregate().SetMaxTime(2 * time.Second)
    cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline, opts)
    for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        records := model.DData{}
        err = cursor.Decode(&records)
    }
```

The structure of Data is:

```
type DData struct {
    Name               string       `json:"name" bson:"name"` 
    Data               interface{}  `json:"data" bson:"data"`
    UpdatedAt          time.Time    `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
    SyncedAt           time.Time     `json:"synced_at" bson:"synced_at"`
}
```

Data in collection is of the form:

```
{
    "name":"Vallabh",
    "data":{
        "field1":"value1",
        "field2":"value2",
        "field3":"value3",
    },
    "updated_at":2021-08-17T09:43:27Z,
    "synced_at":2021-08-07T09:43:27Z
}
```

But with above query I am getting data in the form:

```
{
    "name":"Vallabh",
    "data":[
        {
            "key":"field1",
            "value":"value1"
        },
        {
            "key":"field2",
            "value":"value2"
        },
        {
            "key":"field3",
            "value":"value3"
        }
    }],
    "updated_at":"2021-08-17T09:43:27Z",
    "synced_at":"2021-08-07T09:43:27Z"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Its happening only when field type is an interface in struct.

Answer (score 2):

@VallabhLakade I had similar concern like this and tried the below way that helped .

So basically what's the problem is that the [mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) defaults to unmarshalling as `bson.D` for structs of type `interface{}`  where as `mgo` [mgo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo) defaults to `bson.M` .

So we will have to add the below code while trying to establish connection with `mongo-db` , `SetRegistry()` options as `clientOpts` To map the old mgo behavior, so that `mongo-driver` defaults to `bson.M` while unmarshalling structs of type `interface{}` , and this should not display the values back as `key-value` pair

```
    tM := reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{})
    reg := bson.NewRegistryBuilder().RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.EmbeddedDocument, tM).Build()
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(SOMEURI).SetAuth(authVal).SetRegistry(reg)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```

Reference -> [MongoDB document returns array of key value pair in go mongo-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74418871/mongodb-document-returns-array-of-key-value-pair-in-go-mongo-driver/74423240#74423240)

Answer (score 1):

We also faced the same issue once, where we made two structs one using the interface and another using a struct.

1. When you want to update or Insert you can use the interface.
2. When you want to fetch from database you have to create another structure  which using struct as the type for the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
type DData struct {
    Name               string             `json:"name" bson:"name"` 
    Data               map[string]string  `json:"data" bson:"data"`
    UpdatedAt          time.Time          `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
    SyncedAt           time.Time          `json:"synced_at" bson:"synced_at"`
}
```

Always use the type if you know it beforehand, with `interface{}` the burden is on the library to find out what the type is. If you expect the varied values in the map you can use `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: Data can even have array, string or any other type in it. Thats why I have kept it interface.

Comment: @Nick is ther any other alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Found a very weird solution to this problem where I decoded it to bson.M{}, then marshalled it and unmarshalled it to my struct. I am sure there are better ways but this one worked for me.

```
for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        tempResult := bson.M{}
        err = decode(cursor, &tempResult)
        if err != nil {
            logger.LogErrorf(err, "error while decoding")
            continue
        }
        obj, err := marshal(tempResult)
        if err != nil {
            logger.LogErrorf(err, "error while marshalling")
            continue
        }
        var data model.DData
        err = json.Unmarshal(obj, &data)
        if err != nil {
            tenant.LogError(err, "error while marshalling")
            continue
        }
}
```

Comment: I hit into similar problem , is there any other better solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

@Vallabh you shall use `mgocompat` too something like below this should mimic the old `mgo` behavior

```
registry := mgocompat.NewRegistryBuilder().Build()
connectOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(SOMEURI).SetAuth(info).SetRegistry(registry)
```