# MongoDB document returns array of key value pair in go mongo-driver

Tags: json, mongodb, go, driver, bson

In our code base we have a function which merges two structs , something like below .

```
func CombineStruct(s1 interface{}, s2 interface{}) error {
    data, err := json.Marshal(s1)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, s2)
}
```

We use the above func to combine two structs something like below .

```
m := model.SomeModel{}
CombineStruct(someStruct, &m)
//above line merges two structs
```

Also currently all our structs has only `json` tags not `bson` tags yet, should we need to add `bson` tags in all the places ?

```
for ex : 

type someStruct struct {
    Field1  string       `json:"field1"`
    Field2  string       `json:"field2"`
    Field3  interface{}  `json:"field2"`

}
```

In the above `someStruct` we have fields of type interface too!

Now the issue that i'm facing is wherever we combine the struct I see those object data in `mongoDB` as array of `key-value` pair something like below :

```
    "studentDetails" : [ 
        {
            "Key" : "Details",
            "Value" : [ 
                [ 
                    {
                        "Key" : "Name",
                        "Value" : "Bob"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Value" : "21",
                        "Key" : "Age"
                    } 

                ]
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Key" : "Enrolled",
            "Value" : false
        } 

    ],
```

But I want this to be displayed like something like below . Not like `key-value` pair.

```
    "studentDetails" : {
        "Details" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "serverdr",
                "age" : 21

            }, 
            {
                "Enrolled" : false

            }
        ],
```

It was displaying objects like above way in our old global sing [mgo](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo) driver .But using the new [go-mongo](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) driver when we combine two structs using the `CombineStruct()` function it `displays` as array of key value pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried something like below and that worked like a charm :)

So basically what's the problem is that the [mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) defaults to unmarshalling as `bson.D` for structs of type `interface{}`  where as `mgo` [mgo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo) defaults to `bson.M` .

So we will have to add the below code while trying to establish connection with `mongo-db` , `SetRegistry()` options as `clientOpts` To map the old mgo behavior, so that `mongo-driver` defaults to `bson.M` while unmarshalling structs of type `interface{}` , and this should not display the values back as `key-value` pair

```
    tM := reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{})
    reg := bson.NewRegistryBuilder().RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.EmbeddedDocument, tM).Build()
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(SOMEURI).SetAuth(authVal).SetRegistry(reg)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```